# Clearing a drop down input based off the value of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, conditional-formatting, data-validation

I'm building a stock control system in excel.

Each item has the following:

- Quantity in stock
- Reorder level
- Order stock?
- Ordered?

The idea is that when quantity <= reorder level, the "Order stock?" cell for that product will say "Yes" and highlight in red using conditional formatting. This is implemented and is a simple IF statement. What should happen is that if this box displays "Yes", the staff member can choose either blank or "Yes" from a dropdown in the ordered column, so that other staff members don't reorder the same product. Again, this works.

The issue is that I would like to clear the Ordered? cell when the order stock cell is blank. This means that when the product is then delivered and the quantity is updated, the "ordered?" cell won't still say yes.

I have read through numerous excel tutorials on the internet but none seem to fit the issue. I tried to use an IF(AND(),List,"") command however it was rejected by excel.

[A picture can be found here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deiju.png)

Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

I'm still struggling with this. I've used a slight variation of the code suggested as an answer:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim oS As Long, i As Integer
oS = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).row

' Loop through each row, I = "Reorder?" and J = ""
If Target.Column = 2 Then
    For i = 1 To oS
        ' If I is blank, set J to blank
        If Cells(i, "I").Value = "" Then
            Cells(i, "J").Value = ""
        End If
        ' If J is Yes, set I to blank
        If Cells(i, "J").Value = "Yes" Then
            Cells(i, "I").Value = ""
        End If
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

However when I compile this and then save the workbook, it seems to have no effect. The workbook can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bvp8q8yflwh4fq3/stockSystem.xlsm?dl=0) if anyone wants to play around.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot control a different cell with a function, than the cell that contains it, and you cannot add a function to a cell with data validation active. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

So the way I would approach this would be using VBA instead.
And the simplest way that I can think of, is the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim oS As Long, i As Integer
oS = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
If Target.Column = 2 Then
    For i = 1 To oS
        If Cells(i, "I").Value = "" Then
            Cells(i, "J").Value = ""
        End If
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Entered in the code for the "stock" worksheet. 
Maybe that, perhaps with some modification would work for you?

Comment: I assume it will work, however I've never really done anything with VBA. Do you know of any way to do it without VBA/macros?

Comment: @lukecolli98 Unless using a macro causes problems, it's a very easy thing to use. I didn't give much explanation on how to apply it, but if there is need of any clarification, do feel free to ask.
I tried the approach of using a formula inside of the data validation. And while I did manage to remove the ordered "yes" when the stock "yes" dissapeared, it unfortunately also reappeared as soon as the stock "yes" did. So it never got removed, just hidden while in stock.

Comment: Hi Christofer, I've had a quick go at implementing this but I'm struggling to get it to do as you described. Would you be able to point me in the right direction?